# How to fix Illegal use of floating point error in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, turbo-c++

I am getting type mismatch and illegal use of floating point error in this C++ program in Turbo C++.
Here I am trying to illustrate GO BACK n ARQ protocol but I am not getting why ws variable is involved with error.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int ws,sf,ef,m;       //Type mismatch error
int i,ack[50];
char ch;

void send(int sf){
for(i=sf;i<=(ws-1);i++){
    cout<<"\n\n\nFrame "<<i<<" got acknowledged?(y/n)";
    cin>>ch;
    if(ch=='y'){
        ack[i]=1;
        cout<<"Acknowledgement recieved for frame "<<i;
        }
    if(ch=='n'){
        cout<<"Acknowledgement not recieved for frame "<<i;
        ack[i]=0;
        }
    }
    }
int check()
{
for(int k=0;k<=(ws-1);k++)
{
if(ack[k]==0)
return 1;
}
return 0;
}

int main()
{
int m;
cout<<"Enter the size of data";
cin>>m;
ws=pow(2,m)-1;         //illegal floating point error
sf=0;
ef=sf+ws-1;
send(0);
while(check())
{
for(i=0;i<ws-1;i++)
{
    if(ack[i]==0)
    {
    send(i);
    }
}
}
cout<<"Packet recieved";

getch();
return 0;
}
```

I want to use ws as a global variable that is used in other functions.

Comment: Turbo C++ is so old and broken that it really doesn't deserve to be called a C++ compiler. UPGRADE! Also, realize that our answers to your questions may not work with Turbo C++, as what it accepts is too far away from standard C++.

Comment: I'm suggesting a compiler upgrade too, if this is not standard-compliant there's little thing we can do

Comment: Can you paste the exact error?

Comment: Turbo C++ compiles a long obsolete language that used to be called C++. It is very different from the language that is called C++ today. Tags edited to reflect the fact. Do not use Turbo C++.

Comment: You're probably name clashing with `std::ws` by importing everything with `#include <iostream>`, name your `ws` variable differently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a name clash: ws is already defined in iostream.h